# Online text-editor - how to fix my code properly?

Tags: javascript, angular

(javascript, angular/cli)

I am creating an online text editor with "contenteditable" div element. 
Clicking on a button, a new code HTML tag will be inserted to the document at the position of the cursor, which can be modified too.

If the tag is inserted at the last position of the document, the user cannot escape from the code HTML tag. I have added a line-break every time a code tag is inserted, but in case the user deletes it with backspace, the cursor enters in the code tag again, and the loop continues...

I am thinking about onfocus and onblur events, for the case the user would click out of the code tag, it would return the contenteditable property false for that element, so that if the user would use the backspace after the tag, it would delete the whole tag with its content (I think, it would be far better).

**However, focus and blur events are not listening to non-input tags.**

```
  test(element){
      let sel, range;
      if(window.getSelection && (sel = window.getSelection()).rangeCount){
         range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
         range.collapse(true);

         let code = document.createElement("code");
         code.className="myCode";
         code.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Code example"));

         code.contentEditable="false";

         range.insertNode(code);
         range.setStartAfter(code);
         range.collapse(true);

         sel.removeAllRanges();
         sel.addRange(range);

         //adding whitespace at the end of the document

         element.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<br>');
   }
 }
```

Do you have any advice how could I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I solved the problem, not by using focus and blur events (as they are not supported by contenteditable HTMLelements, but with nodeName checking on selection.

The user has to click on the code tag to write in it(make it contenteditable), and clicking or stepping out of the code element will switch it back to contenteditable = "false". The same function is binded to click and keydown event.

```
selectionTest(content){
 if(document.querySelector("code")){                     //if there is no CODE element, return.
  if(document.getSelection){
    let sel = document.getSelection();                  
    let docs = document.querySelectorAll("code");       //Get all CODE elements     

    if(sel.baseNode.parentElement.nodeName === "CODE"){ // if the clicked element is CODE
      if(docs[0].contentEditable === "true"){           // and if the code contenteditable property is true
        return console.log("already true");             // quit the function
      } else {                                          // otherwise
        for(let i = 0 ; i < docs.length; i++){          // loop through and set all code tags to contenteditable
          docs[i].contentEditable = "true";
        }
      }
    } else {                                            // Otherwise if it is not CODE element...
      if(docs[0].contentEditable === "false"){
        return console.log("already false");
      } else {
        for(let i = 0 ; i < docs.length; i++){
          docs[i].contentEditable = "false";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop when the user presses backspace to check if it is at the end of a tag, then loop through to find where the tag begins, then use .splice() to remove the tag and everything in it.